# VNC Viewer couldn't access to a Mac from Windows 10

Tags: macos, mac, windows, mac-mini, remote-desktop

I'm trying to remote a mac-Laptop from a windows-Laptop with VNC Viewer 6.21.920. T'm getting this "An authentication error occurred. See the VNC Server error log for details". It's working as fine with an old version (VNC Viewer 5.1.0).

Any ideas what I should try next to resolve this?

Comment: Did you check that the password or ssh key is well configured in may vnc viewer version ?

Answer (score 1):

May be this help :
From **VNC Viewer 6.19.325 for desktop computers released**

> In order to connect to remote computers, you must enter two separate sets of credentials; your RealVNC account email address and password to sign in, and then the system (username and) password expected by VNC Server to authenticate. It should now be clearer which set you have to enter when.

Comment: This is excellent. I also like to use putty and ssh to test things like this. It is easier to make sure I'm using  (or they're using) the correct user / password to screen share. I dislike setting a "VNC password" to get in since it can confuse people which password is used where when you change them over time.